# Keep Track of Number of Bytes Read

Tags: python, string, byte

I would like to implement a command line progress bar for one of my programs IN PYTHON which reads text from a file line by line.

I can implement the progress scale in one of two ways:

1. (number of lines / total lines)   or
2. (number of bytes completed / bytes total)

I don't care which, but `"number of lines"` would seem to require me to loop through the entire document (which could be VERY large) just to get the value for `"total lines"`.

This seems extremely inefficient.  I was thinking outside the box and thought perhaps if I took the size of the file (easier to get?) and kept track of the number of bytes that have been read, it might make for a good progress bar metric.

I can use `os.path.getsize(file)` or `os.stat(file).st_size` to retrieve the size of the file, but I have not yet found a way to keep track of the number of bytes read by `readline()`.  The files I am working with should be encoded in ASCII, or maybe even Unicode, so... should I just determine the encoding used and then record the number of characters read or use `os.getsizeof()` or some `len()` function for each line read?

I am sure there will be problems here.  Any suggestions?

(P.S. - I don't think manually inputting the number of bytes to read at a time will work, because I need to work with each line individually;  or else I will need to split it up afterwards by "\n"'s.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bytesread = 0
while True:
  line = fh.readline()
  if line == '':
    break
  bytesread += len(line)
```

Or, a little shorter:

```
bytesread = 0
for line in fh:
  bytesread += len(line)
```

Using `os.path.getsize()` (or `os.stat`) is an efficient way of determining the file size.

Comment: Instead of actually using `len` on the `data`. You could also use `file.tell()` to get the current position and get rid of most of the tracking required.

Comment: I think this is not correct for byte count. I believe "len" is the number of characters and not the number of bytes. A character may be more than one byte. I think you need something like `bytesread  += len(line.encode('utf-8'))` but it depends on what character encoding you intend to use.

Comment: @Yepher there's a difference between Python 2 (which was still the most-used version at the time of posting this answer) and Python 3 (I think the former counts bytes, the latter counts characters).