# Returning number of bytes in stream relative to position

Tags: python, byte, bytesio

I'm currently reading in a stream of live data and would like to try and see if there's a way to return the current number of bytes left in the stream from my current position.

In other words, lets say I read in a stream that has ended whose length is 10 bytes. If I read 3 bytes starting from the beginning, I want to know that I have 7 bytes left.

A solution I could possibly do is recording the number of bytes read but was wondering if BytesIO or any other byte handling type keeps track of its current position in the stream and what that position is. I know getbuffer().nbytes seems to keep track of the entire buffer but I haven't seen anything that keeps track of the number of bytes read, in which I could then take the difference to achieve my answer.

Edit: I'd like to note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423817/keep-track-of-number-of-bytes-read) exists but isn't an implementation I'm looking at. This keeps track of it through the user itself, not a pre-existing data *structure*? in Python.

Comment: `BytesIO` inherits indirectly from `IOBase` which provides the `tell()` method. If `seek()` wasn't called before, it `tell`s how many bytes were written to or read from the buffer already.

Comment: @MichaelButscher No idea how I glanced over this but that's exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: When all my writing is done, I'm calling `seek(0, io.SEEK_END)` before `tell()` to get the actual number of bytes written.